# Effect in Text - objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, effects

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lF60tKu.png]

I have the sources of these letters and I am trying to create the gray effect around in objective-c.
But I can not, does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [GSBorderLabel](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/GSBorderLabel).

It's good because it adds **outer border** and not inner border on characters and it's very easy to customise it.

**For example:**

```
GSBorderLabel *myLabel = [[GSBorderLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 300, 100)];
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
myLabel.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor];
myLabel.borderWidth = 20;
myLabel.text = @"Review";
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Party LET" size:60.0];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting iOS 6 and up, there isn't much over head for this. You can simply use [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to add a stroke to an existing font. Mind you, this will not add the stroke to the font, just render it on screen.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSStrokeColorAttributeName: [UIColor grayColor], NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @3};

NSString *inputText = @"Some text";
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:inputText attributes:attributes];

[self.someLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

....

```
    titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    titleLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
    titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    titleLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
```